The return of the king
A Probability problem arising from a chessboard! If a king is in a8, which is the probability to return to a8 on his second move? (A chess king can move 1 square to any direction). If I count all possible moves I can find 3 with an a8-return. So I thought the probability is $\frac{3}{18}=\frac{1}{6}$. However, if i make a diagram the probability seems to be $\frac{1}{3}.\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{3}.\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{3}.\frac{1}{8}=\frac{7}{40}$ which is different from the above. Which is the right solution?


Is this a problem about chess?

Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its
wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you
is grounds for closing.

You’ll need to precisely state the problem and the moves that are allowed to get useful answers. What is a8? What are the probabilities of each move? What is your diagram? Etc

If at each step the king moves to one of the $3$, $5$ or $8$ adjacent squares with equal probability, then your second approach is correct.  You could see this as a Markov chain.

The techniques applied in a closely related question provide insight into this (simpler) version.

I suppose you are considering this as a discrete random walk and the king can move to any adjacent field with equal probability?

Does King not moving twice count as a solution? (I.e. other piece(s) move instead on turns 1 and 2.) If so, might want to think about what that, and also what King not moving on the first move, but moving on the second move does to your sample space.


If I count all possible moves I can find 3 with an a8-return. So I thought the probability is $\frac{3}{18}=\frac{1}{6}$. However, if i make a diagram the probability seems to be $\frac{1}{3}.\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{3}.\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{3}.\frac{1}{8}=\frac{7}{40}$ which is different from the above. Which is the right solution?

Counting all moves is not the right solution because not all moves have the same probability of occuring.
